# Does Microsoft Graph API support change notifications with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, change-notification, azureadgraph-deprecation

I'm trying to get change notifications for users to work with my application connected to Azure AD B2C.

I followed the following tutorial and the subscription is created successfully but I never get any change notification:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/1-introduction

After a bit of research I found some statements mentioning that B2C is not supported by Graph API:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations

  > Azure AD B2C tenants are not supported.
- Blog entry from 2016

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aadgraphteam/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph

    > Manage users in a B2C tenant (set local accounts, sign in names), Coming soon (preview)
- [Do not receive notifications about user profile updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337828/do-not-receive-notifications-about-user-profile-updates)

I wonder whether this still holds true especially because Microsoft announced that `Azure AD Graph API` should not be used anymore:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/update-your-applications-to-use-microsoft-authentication-library/ba-p/1257363

I ask this question here because Microsoft support redirected me to SO to ask questions about Graph API.

**TLDR;**

Does Microsoft Graph API support change notifications with Azure AD B2C in 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Graph API does not support change notifications with Azure AD B2C as of August 2020. Nor does AAD Graph support change notifications with Azure AD B2C as of August 2020.

You could use Azure Monitor and Event hubs to harvest events from the Audit Logs, such as a Sign Up event.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

Comment: Great, a direct answer from the B2C team. Now I know for sure that it is the wrong approach right now and I have also considered audit log processing. Is there a plan on when to implement change notifications with support for B2C?

Comment: No plans for "change notifications" to come to AAD B2C.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT - would you have an example code for this? We have spent whole day trying to get notifications to work only to land on this stack overflow answer :(

Comment: Did you check the doc? Once you have it setup, there is a Notifications menu in the App Insights resource, where you can create alert logic. In the doc, we provide some examples of the types of query you can run. You can check Kusto docs to learn about the query language.